# What is the purpose of the picture in the deposit boxes on Firestarter?

Tags: payday-2

On day 3 of the mission, you record the burning of the Mendoza's money that is inside of a vault. During this time, you can open up some deposit boxes.  By chance, one of the boxes can contain a picture of what looks like hockey players.  You can even pick it up as if it was loose loot, but no notification of how much it is worth pops up.

The picture of the picture is below:

[image: Hockey Players]

I believe I have also seen this picture on one other mission, though I don't remember which.  What is the point of it? Anything at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the picture of the Overkill Hockey Team!  Finding this photo unlocks the achievement [The First Line](http://www.trueachievements.com/a178655/the-first-line-achievement.htm).

As DJ Pirtu points out in comments, The Elephant can also task you with collecting it as a Daily Side Job.

Comment: It can also be one of your [Daily Side Jobs](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Side_Jobs)